# Continuity of derivatives in baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is an excerpt from  *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, III edition under the section titled "Continuity of Derivatives"

> We have already seen that a function $f$ may have a derivative $f'$ which exists at every point, but is discontinuous at some point. However, not every function is a derivative. In particular, derivatives which exist at every point of an interval have one important property in common with functions which are continuous on an interval.

$\ldots$ and he proceeds to show that the derivative of a real valued function on an interval possesses a certain property of continuous functions.

I am not able to understand the **second** sentence i.e., "not every function is a derivative". Did he mean to say "not every function *has* a derivative"? If it so I am not able to see the connection between this and the last sentence.

I **do** understand meaning of the final sentence. I am just not able to link it up with the second statement.

Please help me clarify this.

Comment: No, he said it right.  Any derivative must enjoy the intermediate value property, so any function without this cannot be a derivative itself.

Comment: No, he meant to say what he wrote: not every function is the derivative of some other function. By Darboux theorem, the derivative of a function over some interval may not be continuous, but it posseses the intermediate value property, so a function not fulfiling this cannot be the derivative of another function.

Comment: Derivatives need not be continuous, but they must satisfy something like the intermediate value theorem. Any function not satisfying this property is therefore not a derivative (not that it doesn't have a derivative. it itself cannot be the derivative of any function)

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful comments. Now everything makes perfect sense!